# В некоторых браузерах не обновляется название приложения

Tags: android, google-play

Есть приложение в Play Market'е.
Изначально было название приложения одно.
Я 12 часов назад его поменял на другое.

При поиске из Хрома - показывает старое название.
При поиске из ФФ - показывает новое название.

Почему так происходит ?

Comment: Попробуйте почистить кеш браузера

Comment: Ctrl + F5 на вашем сайте

Comment: @VAndrJ, не помогло..

Comment: @АлексейСоловьев, не помогло..

Comment: Описание было только на русском языке? Если нет, то может быть забыли на другом языке название изменить?

Comment: @АндроидАндроид, спасибо! Забыл изменить в русском:) Напишите ответ, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С данной проблемой можно сталкиваться при использовании мультиязычного описания приложения. Не забываем изменять название на каждый распространяемый язык=)
P.S. Сам с таким сталкивался пару раз